# iOS hold permanent objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I would like to know what is the best way to hold permanent objects.
For example:
I have a game that user creates his own character, in the creation process he has to choose eyes, mouth, cloths etc. for his character.

These character propeties are permanent, they are part of the app.
What's the best way to hold their data and retrieve it into an `NSObject` when needed?

Great Thanks

Comment: Use a database. SQLite works well. There are only several thousands of examples of this on the internet. Doing some research will serve you well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite, Core Data, or plists.  If it is a small amount of data, NSUserDefaults.